# Entity Framework Core still picks up old column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I recently delete a column `ConversationId` from my tables. When I start to debug my service and try to save I am getting an error:

> Invalid column name 'ConversationId'.

Code:

```
public class AstootContext : DbContext
{
    public AstootContext(DbContextOptions<AstootContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ServiceRequest> ServiceRequests { get; set; }
}
```

And my entity looks like this:

```
public class ServiceRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SenderUserId { get; set; }
    public int PriceTypeId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool IsAccepted { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
}
```

All references to `ConversationId` were removed from the code, I've rebuilt, yet I'm still getting this error and I don't understand why.

This is my SQL Server table as you can see there is no `ConversationId`:

[image]

Is there a secret cache that I need to delete or something I have to run to update this?

Comment: I think you can try to run `migrations` again to update the modified column

Comment: @HaHoang I'm not using Migrations currently, My DB does not reflect my Foreign Key structure

Comment: Sounds like you have an entity called `Conversation` having collection navigation property like `public ICollection<ServiceRequest> ServiceRequests { get; set; }`, don't you?

Comment: Once you have your model (from exist database), you should be used Migrations to keep the database synchronized with any changes to the model.

Comment: @IvanStoev that was it, thanks. if you post that as an answer I will mark it correct

Answer (score 18, accepted):

EF Core is code based ORM, with the most important here being the M - Mapper. It doesn't matter what the actual database structure is, the important is what EF *thinks** it is based on your code model (entity classes and their properties, combined with data annotations, fluent configuration and set of conventions).

So the problem should originate from code. Since you've removed the *explicit* property, it should be caused by [shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties). And as explained in the documentation link, *shadow* properties are usually introduced by convention from relationships:

> Shadow properties can be created by convention when a relationship is discovered but no foreign key property is found in the dependent entity class. In this case, a shadow foreign key property will be introduced.

The documentation also explains the naming rules applied in different scenarios.

A shadow property called `ConversationId` can be introduced in a several ways, but according to the provided information, the most likely cause is to have an entity class called `Conversation` defining one-to-many relationship with `ServiceRequest` by having a collection type navigation property:

```
public class Conversation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public ICollection<ServiceRequest> ServiceRequests { get; set; }
}
```

Which according to your comment was indeed the case.

For completeness, here are some other possible scenarios generating such property:

(1) No collection navigation property in `Conversation`, reference navigation property in `ServiceRequest`:

```
public class Conversation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class ServiceRequest
{
    // ...
    public Conversation Conversation { get; set; }
}
```

(2) No navigation properties in `Conversation` and `ServiceRequest`, fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Conversation>()
    .HasMany<ServiceRequest>();
```

or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceRequest>()
    .HasOne<Conversation>();
```

or variations of the above.

(3) No relationship involved, shadow property created through fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceRequest>()
    .Property<int>("ConversationId");
```