# Invalid Column Name after renaming

Tags: asp.net-boilerplate

I have renamed a property of one of my models from CompanyId to CustomerId. I went into the database and renamed the column there as well.

I'm getting an error that 'CompanyId is an invalid column name'. This old column name is no longer referenced anywhere in my code, so I don't know where this is coming from.

If I rename the column in the database back to CompanyId, and keep the property name still as CustomerId, it then gives me an error that 'CustomerId is an invalid column name.'. So it knows that the column should be called CustomerId, but when I change the column name in the DB to CustomerId, then it complains the old column name doesn't exist.

I'm not using the built in EF Migration, I have a separate SQL Database project that I'm using to manage the schema outside of ABP. Is there some kind of cache somewhere that is keeping track of the properties/columns/etc?

**solved:**
This [Entity Framework Core still picks up old column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685313/entity-framework-core-still-picks-up-old-column) did the trick. It turned out Entity Framework Shadow Properties were the issue. I had another class that had a collection of Companies so it had expected this class had a CompanyId on it.

Comment: Check the error in Logs.txt.

Answer (score 0):

This Entity Framework Core still picks up old column did the trick. It turned out Entity Framework Shadow Properties were the issue. I had another class that had a collection of Companies so it had expected this class had a CompanyId on it.